# Gun should shoot only when button is touched instead of entire screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've made a 3d game and I have a first person controller, control by a joystick. I want my player to shoot only when I touch a button on the screen, but now my player shoots if I touch anything on the screen. This is the script for the shoot function:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;
    public Camera fpsCam;
    public Button button;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Calls the TaskOnClick/TaskWithParameters/ButtonClicked method when you click the Button
       button.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()

    {
        Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10;
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forward, Color.green);


    }
    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
       if( Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
            if(target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(collision.contacts[0].point, collision.contacts[0].normal, Color.green, 2, false);

    }


    void TaskOnClick()
    {

            Shoot();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Shoot()` method runs whenever you press the "Fire1" button, since the only check you are doing is if `(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))`.

If you want to depend on a button to fire you need to take this part of the code out and call `Shoot()` whenever you click the button.

You can add the event to the button using code, as explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html)

```c#
  public Button m_YourFirstButton;

    void Start()
    {
        //Calls the TaskOnClick/TaskWithParameters/ButtonClicked method when you click the Button
        m_YourFirstButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        //Output this to console when Button1 or Button3 is clicked
        Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
    }
```

or you could call it from the inspector by referencing your Gun monobehaviour.

Comment: So I removed  if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();

        } -------- and add at TaskOnClick()  { Shoot(); } but still when I touch outside the button the gun shot anyway

Comment: ok, I  update the code, my gun still shot if I touch anything on the screen

Comment: Could you maybe post some screenshots of your inspector? and check if there isn`t anything else that could have called `Shoot()`.